# Multi Container beanstalk deployment with prebuilt images only

Tags: docker, elastic-beanstalk

I have a CI system already setup which builds and pushes the docker images to ECR. In `Dockerrun.aws.json` file I am using those images (links) to run multi docker container beanstalk environment.

Sample `Dockerrun.aws.json`

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "volumes": [
    {
      "name": "web-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/web-app"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "api-service",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/api-service"
      }
    }
  ],
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "api-service",
      "image": "somekey.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/api-service",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 800,
      "privileged": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "/root/api-service/before_run.sh"
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "api-service",
          "containerPath": "/root/api-service"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "web-app",
      "image": "somekey.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/web-app",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 800,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
          "value": "staging"
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "/root/web-app/before_run.sh"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "web-app",
          "containerPath": "/root/web-app"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is beanstalk is not using those images. Instead it is using code that resides in `/var/current/app/api-service` folder.

So, If I just upload `Dockerrun.aws.json` file it fails with `No file or directory` as there are no files in `/var/current/app/api-service`. Similarly if I add folder `api-service` along with `Dockerrun.aws.json` and then deploy. It works.

The idea is to simply pull those docker images from ECR and run them without deploying additional source code to container.

P.S: I have added ECR access to eb instance profile. And I can see images being pulled correctly. Even I can run them manually without any issue on remote instance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this by using following approach.

Remove `mountpoints` from `Dockerrun.aws.json` to let the docker use its own workspace.

So, here is the new `Dockerrun.aws.json`

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,

  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "api-service",
      "image": "somekey.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/api-service",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 800,
      "privileged": true,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "/root/api-service/before_run.sh"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "web-app",
      "image": "somekey.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/web-app",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 800,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "ENVIRONMENT",
          "value": "staging"
        }
      ],
      "command": [
        "/bin/bash",
        "/root/web-app/before_run.sh"
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```